# gaussian integral for a vector infinitesimal in Fourier part of Ewald summation

Tags: vectors, gaussian-integral

When I was deriving the Fourier part of Ewald summation (see P5 in this [pdf](https://www.roma1.infn.it/%7Esciortif/didattica/SIMATOM/SIMATOM/ewald.pdf) or P287 in this [book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=5qTzldS9ROIC&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=understanding%20molecular%20simulation&ots=nHPQTu36Qi&sig=PO6caYH0yuTCO9WbjoY3_njPH_E#v=onepage&q=understanding%20molecular%20simulation&f=false)), I am stuck on the charge density part $\rho(\mathrm k)$ in Fourier space. The primitive formula is as followed,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho(\mathrm k)
& =\int_V \mathrm d\mathbf r\rho(\mathbf r)e^{-\mathrm i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}\\
&=\int_{\rm all\ space} \mathrm d\mathbf r e^{-\mathrm i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} q_j{(\frac{\alpha}{\pi})}^{3/2} e^{-\alpha|\mathbf r-\mathbf r_j|}\\
& =\int_{\rm all\ space} \mathrm d \mathbf r \sum\limits_{j=1}^N q_j(\frac{\alpha}{\pi})^{3/2} e^{-(\frac{\mathrm i\mathbf k}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}+\sqrt{\alpha}(\mathbf r-\mathbf r_j)^2)}e^{-\mathrm i\mathbf k \mathbf r_j} e^{-\frac{k^2}{4\alpha}}
\end{aligned}
$$

There is a vector $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)$, and how to compute the integral above, which can be simplified as

$$\int_{\rm{all\ space}} e^{-\mathbf r^2} {\mathrm d}{\mathbf r}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I guess I found the key to solving the integral. Is the key the Fubini's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Fubini's theorem, we can solve the problem.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\rm all\ space} e^{-(\sqrt \alpha \mathbf r)^2} \mathrm d \mathbf r
&=\int_{\rm all\ space} e^{-(\sqrt \alpha \mathbf r)^2} \mathrm d(\frac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\sqrt \alpha\mathbf r)
\\&=\iiint e^{-\alpha(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \mathrm d(\frac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\sqrt \alpha x,\frac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\sqrt \alpha y,\frac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\sqrt \alpha z)
\\&=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\mathrm d(\sqrt \alpha z) \int\frac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\mathrm d(\sqrt \alpha y) \int\frac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\mathrm d(\sqrt \alpha x) e^{-\alpha x^2} e^{-\alpha y^2} e^{-\alpha z^2}
\\&=(\frac{\pi}{\alpha})^{3/2}
\end{aligned}
$$